# Twos Complement Addition. -48 - 23. Is it necessary to use 8-bit representation?

Tags: twos-complement

The approach I am using to solve this is that I first write both numbers in 2s Complement form.
For this I first convert 48 and 23 to binary, then ones complement the binary representation and add 1.

48 = (0110000), 23 = (0010111) {In Binary Signed Representation)

Now their twos complement are -48 = (1010000), -23 = (1101001).

Now I just add them:

[image]

Now in my textbook it's written that final carry 1 should be discarded. If I discard that I get wrong answer. If I use 8-bit representation instead of 7 bits I get correct answer.

So my question is Why isn't 7-bit representation giving correct answer? Is it necessary to use some 2^n representation?

Answer (score 2):

What you've just encountered is the classic 'overflow' problem. If you only have 7 bits to represent a number, the 'correct answer' is unrepresentable, because it is simply too big to fit within 7 bits. Of course in an ideal case, you would want to keep all the bits to ensure your answer is correct, but this is subject to the limitations of hardware. This is how integers have their associated maximum and minimum value determined(e.g 2,147,483,647 for a 32-bit signed integer).

For some added info, overflow checks are common in programming(automated in some higher level languages, but manual in others), generally if you're adding two numbers with the same sign(both positive/negative) and the end result is of the opposite sign(cuz the most significant bit is removed) then you know an overflow has occurred.